# Forcing Jquery Mobile to reload in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am working on a mobile site that uses Rails and Jquery mobile. The problem is that I have a button which when triggered is suppose to go to a link. The link then starts a controller which generates data to be shown in the page and saved in the database. The problem is that it only works the first time around and when I try doing it again, JQM just loads the cached data and uses ajax, so the page is never reloaded again..

Button:

```
<div data-role="button" data-ajax="false"><%= link_to "Get Basket",basket_path%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place data-role="button" and data-ajax="false" inside your anchor tag, like this:

```
<a href="..." data-role="button" data-ajax="false">...</a>
```